# Redirect stderr and stdout in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, io-redirection, stderr

I want to redirect both [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) of a process to a single file. How do I do that in Bash?

Comment: I'd like to say this is a surprisingly useful question.   Many people do not know how to do this, as they don't have to do so frequently, and it is not the best documented behavior of Bash.

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to see the output (as usual) AND to redirect it to a file. See the answer by Marko below. (I say this here because it's easy to just look at the first accepted answer if that's sufficient to solve a problem, but other answers often provide useful information.)

Answer (score 972, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). It should be:

```
yourcommand &> filename
```

It redirects both standard output and standard error to file *filename*.

Comment: I guess we should not use &> as it is not in POSIX, and common shells such as "dash" do not support it.

Comment: An extra hint: If you use this in a script, make sure it starts with `#!/bin/bash` rather than `#!/bin/sh`, since in requires bash.

Comment: it is the simplest way. unfortunately there is needed redirect outputs for all commands inside the scripts, or .... creating subprocess using parentheses. better way described quizad using exec calls for reopen script outputs.

Comment: On my machine, this puts `yourcommand` in the background and redirects stdout to `filename` but not stderr.

Comment: Or &>> to append instead of overwrite.

Comment: @AlexanderGonchiy What shell are you using? This only works to redirect to filepath in bash.

Comment: domain wiki.bash-hackers.org is parked. The site contains ads only.

Answer (score 571):

```
do_something 2>&1 | tee -a some_file
```

This is going to redirect standard error to standard output and standard output to `some_file` **and** print it to standard output.

Comment: On AIX (ksh) your solution works. The accepted answer `do_something &>filename` doesn't. +1.

Comment: @Daniel, but this question is specifically about bash

Comment: I get `Ambiguous output redirect.` Any idea why?

Comment: I have a ruby script (which I don't want to modify in any way) that prints error messages in bold red. This ruby script is then invoked from my bash script (which I can modify). When I use the above, it prints the error messages in plain text, minus the formatting. Is there any way to retain on-screen formatting and get the output (both stdout and stderr) in a file as well?

Comment: Note that (by default) this has the side-effect that `$?` no longer refers to the exit status of `do_something`, but the exit status of `tee`.

Comment: Those few words "stderr to stdout and stdout to some_file" helped me understand something I was struggling to understand since long

Comment: Why the pipe to `tee`? Why is this better than using normal file redirection?

Comment: @AlexandreHoldenDaly Depends on your shell. I have run into that problem on tcsh. On bash it works without a problem.

Comment: If you want to overwrite the log file every time, remove the `-a` flag. This flag appends the output to the log file if it exists.

Comment: I need this tattooed on my body somewhere, can never remember the order of the chars!

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

Comment: FYI i just notice `2>&1` and `2>& 1` work. But `2 >&1` does NOT work. There must be no space between 2 and >&.

Answer (score 338):

You can redirect *stderr* to *stdout* and the *stdout* into a file:

```bash
some_command >file.log 2>&1
```

NB: The order of redirection is *significant*.
The following **is not** equivalent.

```bash
some_command 2>&1 >file.log
```

See *[Chapter 20. I/O Redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)*

This format is preferred over the most popular `&>` format that only works in Bash.  In Bourne shell it could be interpreted as running the command in background. Also the format is more readable - *2* (is standard error) redirected to *1* (standard output).

Comment: What is the advantage of this approach over some_command &> file.log?

Comment: If you want to append to a file then you must do it this way: echo "foo" 2>&1 1>> bar.txt   AFAIK there's no way to append using &>

Comment: Argh, sorry, echo "foo" 1>> bar.txt 2>&1

Comment: Why the current approved answer is preferred before this answer is beyond me, why would someone want to use 'tee' if it's not necessary.

Comment: I think the interpretation that 2>&1 redirects stderr to stdout is wrong; I believe it is more accurate to say it sends stderr to the same place that stdout is going at this moment in time.  Thus place 2>&1 *after* the first redirect is essential.

Comment: @SlappyTheFish, actually, there *is* a way: "&>>"
 
From bash man: "
The format for appending standard output and standard error is:
    &>>word 
This is semantically equivalent to
    >>word 2>&1 
"

Comment: re: `what is the advantage ...` -- if you happen to be forced to use a bash enough older than bash 4, then `&>` and `>&` might not even be available.  This syntax has been available since forever-ish.

Comment: If 2>&1 must follow >file then what about merging both streams for piping to "less". Is this ````2>&1 | less```` correct?

Comment: This works, but when I start the script, I want to still be able to type commands on the command line, and I can't here

Comment: +1. Prefer this approach to the now depreacted `&>`, according to: Obsolete and deprecated syntax [Bash Hackers Wiki (DEV 20200708T2203)] : https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete .

Answer (score 245):

```
# Close standard output file descriptor
exec 1<&-
# Close standard error file descriptor
exec 2<&-

# Open standard output as $LOG_FILE file for read and write.
exec 1<>$LOG_FILE

# Redirect standard error to standard output
exec 2>&1

echo "This line will appear in $LOG_FILE, not 'on screen'"
```

Now, a simple echo will write to $LOG_FILE, and it is useful for daemonizing.

To the author of the original post,

It depends what you need to achieve. If you just need to redirect in/out of a command you call from your script, the answers are already given. Mine is about redirecting *within* current script which affects all commands/built-ins (includes forks) after the mentioned code snippet.

---

Another cool solution is about redirecting to both standard error and standard output *and* to log to a log file at once which involves splitting "a stream" into two. This functionality is provided by 'tee' command which can write/append to several file descriptors (files, sockets, pipes, etc.) at once: `tee FILE1 FILE2 ... >(cmd1) >(cmd2) ...`

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2 1> >(tee >(logger -i -t 'my_script_tag') >&3) 2> >(tee >(logger -i -t 'my_script_tag') >&4)
trap 'cleanup' INT QUIT TERM EXIT


get_pids_of_ppid() {
    local ppid="$1"

    RETVAL=''
    local pids=`ps x -o pid,ppid | awk "\\$2 == \\"$ppid\\" { print \\$1 }"`
    RETVAL="$pids"
}


# Needed to kill processes running in background
cleanup() {
    local current_pid element
    local pids=( "$$" )

    running_pids=("${pids[@]}")

    while :; do
        current_pid="${running_pids[0]}"
        [ -z "$current_pid" ] && break

        running_pids=("${running_pids[@]:1}")
        get_pids_of_ppid $current_pid
        local new_pids="$RETVAL"
        [ -z "$new_pids" ] && continue

        for element in $new_pids; do
            running_pids+=("$element")
            pids=("$element" "${pids[@]}")
        done
    done

    kill ${pids[@]} 2>/dev/null
}
```

So, from the beginning. Let's assume we have a terminal connected to */dev/stdout* (file descriptor #1) and /dev/stderr (file descriptor #2). In practice, it could be a pipe, socket or whatever.

- Create [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) (FDs) #3 and #4 and point to the same "location" as #1 and #2 respectively. Changing file descriptor #1 doesn't affect file descriptor #3 from now on. Now, file descriptors #3 and #4 point to standard output and standard error respectively. These will be used as **real** terminal standard output and standard error.
- 1> >(...) redirects standard output to command in parentheses
- Parentheses (sub-shell) executes 'tee', reading from exec's standard output (pipe) and redirects to the 'logger' command via another pipe to the sub-shell in parentheses. At the same time it copies the same input to file descriptor #3 (the terminal)
- the second part, very similar, is about doing the same trick for standard error and file descriptors #2 and #4.

The result of running a script having the above line and additionally this one:

```
echo "Will end up in standard output (terminal) and /var/log/messages"
```

...is as follows:

```
$ ./my_script
Will end up in standard output (terminal) and /var/log/messages

$ tail -n1 /var/log/messages
Sep 23 15:54:03 wks056 my_script_tag[11644]: Will end up in standard output (terminal) and /var/log/messages
```

If you want to see clearer picture, add these two lines to the script:

```
ls -l /proc/self/fd/
ps xf
```

Comment: only one exception. in the first example you wrote: exec 1<>$LOG_FILE . it cause original logfile is allways owerwritten. for real loggin better way is:  exec 1>>$LOG_FILE   it cause log is allways appended.

Comment: That's true although it depends on intentions. My approach is to always create a unique and timestamped log file. The other is to append. Both ways are 'logrotateable'. I prefer separate files which require less parsing but as I said, whatever makes your boat floating :)

Comment: how do you switch back from log file to stdout

Comment: You'd have to save a copy of STDOUT descriptor to let's say #11 by running 'exec 11>&1' before closing FD#1(first line) and when you're finished with file logging, you can redirect it back to STDOUT by adding 'exec 1>&11'. In theory, it should work although, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Your second solution is informative, but what's with all the cleanup code?  It doesn't seem relevant, and if so, only muddles an otherwise good example.  I'd also like to see it reworked slightly so that FDs 1 and 2 aren't redirected to the logger but rather 3 and 4 are so that anything calling this script might manipulate 1 and 2 further under the common assumption the stdout==1 and stderr==2, but my brief experimentation suggests that's more complex.

Comment: I like it better with the cleanup code. It might be a bit of distraction from the core example, but stripping it would make the example incomplete. The net is already full of examples without error handling, or at least a friendly note that it still needs about a hundred lines of code to make is safe to use.

Comment: The cleanup code there is necessary and it removes processes in the background if parent PID is killed or exits for any reason. 'logger' processes might get detached and continue to run while parent process is already gone. This example is a part of bigger script and I always include this snippet(among others) due to infrequent issues here and there.

Comment: I wanted to elaborate on clean-up code. It's a part of script which daemonizes ergo becomes immune to HANG-UP signal. 'tee' and 'logger' are processes spawned by the same PPID and they inherit HUP trap from main bash script. So, once the main process dies they become inherited by init[1]. They will not become zombies(defunc). The clean-up code makes sure that all background tasks are killed, if main script dies. It also applies to any other process which might have been created and running in background.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a hundred times! THAT'S a MINIMUM estimate of how many times I wanted to use a tool like tee and, well, had to invent my own way because I didn't know it existed, and neither did anyone else around me! THANKS HEAPS!

Answer (score 52):

```
bash your_script.sh 1>file.log 2>&1
```

`1>file.log` instructs the shell to send standard output to the file `file.log`, and `2>&1` tells it to redirect standard error (file descriptor 2) to standard output (file descriptor 1).

**Note:** The order matters as liw.fi pointed out, `2>&1 1>file.log` doesn't work.

Comment: To me, the second way makes more sense.

First send all of stderr to stdout, then send stdout to the file.

Why would we want to send stderr to stdout after stdout goes to the file?

Answer (score 23):

Curiously, this works:

```
yourcommand &> filename
```

But this gives a syntax error:

```
yourcommand &>> filename
syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

You have to use:

```
yourcommand 1>> filename 2>&1
```

Comment: `&>>` seems to work on BASH 4:
`$ echo $BASH_VERSION 
4.1.5(1)-release
$ (echo to stdout; echo to stderr > /dev/stderr) &>> /dev/null`

Answer (score 20):

Short answer: `Command >filename 2>&1` or `Command &>filename`

---

Explanation:

Consider the following code which prints the word "stdout" to stdout and the word "stderror" to stderror.

```
$ (echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2)
stdout
stderror
```

Note that the '&' operator tells bash that 2 is a file descriptor (which points to the stderr) and not a file name. If we left out the '&', this command would print `stdout` to stdout, and create a file named "2" and write `stderror` there.

By experimenting with the code above, you can see for yourself exactly how redirection operators work. For instance, by changing which file which of the two descriptors `1,2`, is redirected to `/dev/null` the following two lines of code delete everything from the stdout, and everything from stderror respectively (printing what remains).

```
$ (echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2) 1>/dev/null
stderror
$ (echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2) 2>/dev/null
stdout
```

Now, we can explain why the solution why the following code produces no output:

```
(echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2) >/dev/null 2>&1
```

To truly understand this, I highly recommend you read this [webpage on file descriptor tables](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/). Assuming you have done that reading, we can proceed. Note that Bash processes left to right; thus Bash sees `>/dev/null` first (which is the same as `1>/dev/null`), and sets the file descriptor 1 to point to /dev/null instead of the stdout. Having done this, Bash then moves rightwards and sees `2>&1`. This sets the file descriptor 2 **to point to the same file** as file descriptor 1 (and not to file descriptor 1 itself!!!! (see [this resource on pointers](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/) for more info)) . Since file descriptor 1 points to /dev/null, and  file descriptor 2 points to the same file as file descriptor 1, file descriptor 2 now also points to /dev/null. Thus both file descriptors point to /dev/null, and this is why no output is rendered.

---

To test if you really understand the concept, try to guess the output when we switch the redirection order:

```
(echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2)  2>&1 >/dev/null
```

> stderror

The reasoning here is that evaluating from left to right, Bash sees 2>&1, and thus sets the file descriptor 2 to point to the same place as file descriptor 1, ie stdout. It then sets file descriptor 1 (remember that >/dev/null = 1>/dev/null) to point to >/dev/null, thus deleting everything which would usually be send to to the standard out. Thus all we are left with was that which was not send to stdout in the subshell (the code in the parentheses)- i.e. "stderror".
  The interesting thing to note there is that even though 1 is just a pointer to the stdout, redirecting pointer 2 to 1 via `2>&1` does NOT form a chain of pointers 2 -> 1 -> stdout. If it did, as a result of redirecting 1 to /dev/null, the code `2>&1 >/dev/null` would give the pointer chain 2 -> 1 -> /dev/null, and thus the code would generate nothing, in contrast to what we saw above.

---

Finally, I'd note that there is a simpler way to do this:

From section 3.6.4 [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), we see that we can use the operator `&>` to redirect both stdout and stderr. Thus, to redirect both the stderr and stdout output of any command to `\dev\null` (which deletes the output), we simply type 
`$ command &> /dev/null` 
or in case of my example:

```
$ (echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2) &>/dev/null
```

---

Key takeaways:

- File descriptors behave like pointers (although file descriptors are not the same as file pointers)
- Redirecting a file descriptor "a" to a file descriptor "b" which points to file "f", causes file descriptor "a" to point to the same place as file descriptor b - file "f". It DOES NOT form a chain of pointers a -> b -> f
- Because of the above, order matters, `2>&1 >/dev/null` is != `>/dev/null 2>&1`. One generates output and the other does not!

---

Finally have a look at these great resources:

[Bash Documentation on Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), [An Explanation of File Descriptor Tables](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/), [Introduction to Pointers](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/)

Comment: File descriptors (0, 1, 2) are just offsets into a table.  When 2>&1 is used the effect is slot FD[2] = dup(1) so wherever FD[1] was pointing FD[2] now points to.   When you change FD[1] to point to /dev/null, then FD[1] is changed but it doesn't change the FD[2] slot (which points to stdout).  I use the term dup() because that is the system call that is used to duplicate the file descriptor.

Answer (score 11):

```
LOG_FACILITY="local7.notice"
LOG_TOPIC="my-prog-name"
LOG_TOPIC_OUT="$LOG_TOPIC-out[$$]"
LOG_TOPIC_ERR="$LOG_TOPIC-err[$$]"

exec 3>&1 > >(tee -a /dev/fd/3 | logger -p "$LOG_FACILITY" -t "$LOG_TOPIC_OUT" )
exec 2> >(logger -p "$LOG_FACILITY" -t "$LOG_TOPIC_ERR" )
```

It is related: Writing standard output and standard error to [syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog).

It almost works, but not from [xinetd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinetd) ;(

Comment: I'm guessing it doesn't work because of "/dev/fd/3 Permission denied". Changing to >&3 may help.

Answer (score 10):

I wanted a solution to have the output from stdout plus stderr written into a log file and stderr still on console. So I needed to duplicate the stderr output via tee.

This is the solution I found:

```
command 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 1>>logfile | tee -a logfile
```

- First swap stderr and stdout
- then append the stdout to the log file
- pipe stderr to tee and append it also to the log file

Comment: BTW, this didn't work for me (logfile is empty). |tee has no effect. Instead I got it working using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe

Answer (score 9):

For the situation when "piping" is necessary, you can use [`|&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384999/what-does-mean-in-bash).

For example:

```
echo -ne "15\n100\n" | sort -c |& tee >sort_result.txt
```

or

```
TIMEFORMAT=%R;for i in `seq 1 20` ; do time kubectl get pods | grep node >>js.log ; done |& sort -h
```

These Bash-based solutions can pipe standard output and standard error separately (from standard error of "sort -c", or from standard error to "sort -h").

Comment: This is actually very important, and less known. Good call. You might also want explain what the `&` does, when used in combination with the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

The "easiest" way (Bash 4 only):

```
ls * 2>&- 1>&-
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what [Fernando Fabreti did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-bash/51542989#51542989), I changed the functions slightly and removed the `&-` closing and it worked for me.

```
    function saveStandardOutputs {
      if [ "$OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED" == "false" ]; then
        exec 3>&1
        exec 4>&2
        trap restoreStandardOutputs EXIT
      else
          echo "[ERROR]: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: Cannot save standard outputs because they have been redirected before"
          exit 1;
      fi
  }

  # Parameters: $1 => logfile to write to
  function redirectOutputsToLogfile {
      if [ "$OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED" == "false" ]; then
        LOGFILE=$1
        if [ -z "$LOGFILE" ]; then
            echo "[ERROR]: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: logfile empty [$LOGFILE]"
        fi
        if [ ! -f $LOGFILE ]; then
            touch $LOGFILE
        fi
        if [ ! -f $LOGFILE ]; then
            echo "[ERROR]: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: creating logfile [$LOGFILE]"
            exit 1
        fi
        saveStandardOutputs
        exec 1>>${LOGFILE}
        exec 2>&1
        OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED="true"
      else
        echo "[ERROR]: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: Cannot redirect standard outputs because they have been redirected before"
          exit 1;
      fi
  }

  function restoreStandardOutputs {
      if [ "$OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED" == "true" ]; then
      exec 1>&3   #restore stdout
      exec 2>&4   #restore stderr
      OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED="false"
     fi
  }

  LOGFILE_NAME="tmp/one.log"
  OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED="false"

  echo "this goes to standard output"
  redirectOutputsToLogfile $LOGFILE_NAME
  echo "this goes to logfile"
  echo "${LOGFILE_NAME}"
  restoreStandardOutputs
  echo "After restore this goes to standard output"
```

Answer (score 2):

In situations when you consider using things like `exec 2>&1`, I find it easier to read, if possible, rewriting code using Bash functions like this:

```
function myfunc(){
  [...]
}

myfunc &>mylog.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The following functions can be used to automate the process of toggling outputs beetwen stdout/stderr and a logfile.

```
#!/bin/bash

    #set -x

    # global vars
    OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED="false"
    LOGFILE=/dev/stdout

    # "private" function used by redirect_outputs_to_logfile()
    function save_standard_outputs {
        if [ "$OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED" == "true" ]; then
            echo "[ERROR]: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: Cannot save standard outputs because they have been redirected before"
            exit 1;
        fi
        exec 3>&1
        exec 4>&2

        trap restore_standard_outputs EXIT
    }

    # Params: $1 => logfile to write to
    function redirect_outputs_to_logfile {
        if [ "$OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED" == "true" ]; then
            echo "[ERROR]: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: Cannot redirect standard outputs because they have been redirected before"
            exit 1;
        fi
        LOGFILE=$1
        if [ -z "$LOGFILE" ]; then
            echo "[ERROR]: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: logfile empty [$LOGFILE]"

        fi
        if [ ! -f $LOGFILE ]; then
            touch $LOGFILE
        fi
        if [ ! -f $LOGFILE ]; then
            echo "[ERROR]: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: creating logfile [$LOGFILE]"
            exit 1
        fi

        save_standard_outputs

        exec 1>>${LOGFILE%.log}.log
        exec 2>&1
        OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED="true"
    }

    # "private" function used by save_standard_outputs() 
    function restore_standard_outputs {
        if [ "$OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED" == "false" ]; then
            echo "[ERROR]: ${FUNCNAME[0]}: Cannot restore standard outputs because they have NOT been redirected"
            exit 1;
        fi
        exec 1>&-   #closes FD 1 (logfile)
        exec 2>&-   #closes FD 2 (logfile)
        exec 2>&4   #restore stderr
        exec 1>&3   #restore stdout

        OUTPUTS_REDIRECTED="false"
    }
```

Example of usage inside script:

```
echo "this goes to stdout"
redirect_outputs_to_logfile /tmp/one.log
echo "this goes to logfile"
restore_standard_outputs 
echo "this goes to stdout"
```

Comment: when I use your functions and it attempts to restore standard outputs I get echo: write error: Bad file number the redirect works perfectly... the restore doesn't seem to

Comment: in order to get your script to work on I had to comment out the these lines and I changed the order:  #exec 1>&-   #closes FD 1 (logfile)
        #exec 2>&-   #closes FD 2 (logfile); exec 1>&3   #restore stdout
        exec 2>&4   #restore stderr

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I don't receive any errors when running in CentOS 7, bash 4.2.46.
I have annotated the reference where I got those commands. It's: Ref: http://logan.tw/posts/2016/02/20/open-and-close-files-in-bash/

Comment: I'm running these commands on AIX that is probably why. I added a post for the fix I made.

Answer (score 0):

For [tcsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh), I have to use the following command:

```
command >& file
```

If using `command &> file`, it will give an "Invalid null command" error.