# PHP - Calling .php file from command line produces no output

Tags: command-line, php

I have a simple **cmd.php** page to run commands I enter using **shell_exec ()** and show the output.

- PHP **is** running as CGI
- Entering "php -v" and most commands just show "Content-type: text/html" and then the current page's HTML source.
- However, calling PHP with an invalid parameter (**/usr/bin/php -z**) shows PHPs usage:

  Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f ]
     php  [args...]

  *etc...*

I attached a couple of images to show what I mean.

**PHP -v** doesn't produce expected output

[image: PHP -v doesn't produce expected output]

**PHP -z** shows PHP's usage

[image: PHP -z shows PHP's usage]

Any ideas?

**Edit**

**cmd.php**

```
<?php

    if ( isset ( $_POST['submit'] ) ) :

        $response = shell_exec ( escapeshellcmd ( stripslashes ( $_POST['cmd'] ) ) );

    endif;

?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            pre#response { border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; padding: .5em; }
        </style>
        <title>Command</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="cmd.php" method="post">
            <p><input type="text" name="cmd" id="cmd" value="<?php echo @htmlspecialchars ( stripslashes ( $_POST['cmd'] ) ); ?>" size="50" />
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
        </form>


        <?php
        if ( isset ( $response ) ) :
        ?>

            <pre id="response"><?php

                if ( empty ( $response ) ) :
                    echo 'No response.';
                else :
                    echo htmlspecialchars ( $response );
                endif;
            ?></pre>

        <?php
        endif;
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Can we have a peek at **cmd.php**?

Comment: It should show the version number... I posted the source code.

Comment: Is your FCGI or CGI running in a chroot via a wrapper script?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... you're seeing all of the code I'm using above.

Answer (score 1):

shell_exec() only returns the characters that have been written to the stdout of the executed process, but not stderr. Try [redirecting stderr to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script) so that error messages will be stored in $response.

```
<?php
define('REDIRECT_STDERR', 1);

if ( isset ( $_POST['submit'] ) ) :      
  $cmd = escapeshellcmd ( stripslashes ($_POST['cmd']) );
  if ( defined('REDIRECT_STDERR') && REDIRECT_STDERR ) :
    $cmd .= ' 2>&1';
  endif;
  $response = shell_exec( $cmd );
endif;

?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      pre#response { border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; padding: .5em; }
    </style>
    <title>Command</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="cmd.php" method="post">
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="cmd" id="cmd" value="<?php echo @htmlspecialchars ( stripslashes ( $_POST['cmd'] ) ); ?>" size="50" />
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
      </p>
    </form>


    <?php if ( isset ( $cmd ) ) : ?>
    <fieldset><legend><?php echo htmlspecialchars($cmd); ?></legend>
      <pre id="response"><?php var_dump($repsonse); ?></pre>
    </fieldset>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check php.ini used by php from command line. I had same problem (no output from php command line), tried replacing current php.ini with php.ini-production and command line php started to work fine. It appears that some configuration variables were modified in recent php version (upgraded from 5.3.10 to 5.4.3).