# How to get a readable "script" output?

Tags: linux

When I run a python script I want to capture everything which is output on the screen. When I use the "script" command and capture the log in "typescript" file, the output in not readable when using vi. Its readable using

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect stderr and stdout in a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: What do you mean that the output of the script command is not readable?  I use this all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
python -u yourscript.py 1> log 2> err
```

Or for appending

```
python -u yourscript.py 1>> log 2>> err
```

Answer (score 0):

```
./pyscript.py &> output.txt
```

or:

```
python script.py &> output.txt
```

Note: redirects both *stdout* and *stderr* to output.txt.