# If redirecting STDERR to STDOUT and redirecting STDOUT to a file, why are STDERR messages not showing in the file?

Tags: bash, unix, io-redirection

I made a quick little script, test.sh, that looks like the following:

```
echo "StdErr" > /dev/stderr
echo "StdOut" > /dev/stdout
```

According to the answers to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script), and the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), the following should redirect stderr to stdout from the script above:

```
$ sh /tmp/test.sh 2>&1
```

And indeed it does:

```
$ sh /tmp/test.sh 2>&1 |tee file;
$ cat file
StdErr
StdOut
```

The question that I am wondering is where does the output from stderr go in the following code?

```
$ sh /tmp/test.sh > file 2>&1
$ cat file
StdOut
```

I am using GNU bash, version 4.0.24(2)-release.

Answer (score 3):

Your script writes "StdErr" to the file. Then, the next line overwrites the file with "StdOut".  You should use `>>` if you want to append to the file.  Since you are redirecting, `/dev/stderr` and `/dev/stdout` are regular files, subject to truncation.  Try your test again, but this time make `file` a fifo instead of a regular file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the output to stderr going to the file, as expected:

```
$> sh test.sh > file 2>&1
$> cat file 
StdErr
StdOut
```

This is bash 3.2.48.

```
$> bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on RedHat with Bash version `GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`. On my Mac with Bash and ZSH both works as expected.

```
[13:31:05][user@machine: ~/src]$ bash test
1STD ERR
2STD ERR
3STD OUT
4STD OUT
[13:31:40][user@machine: ~/src]$ bash test >> log 2>&1
[13:31:48][user@machine: ~/src]$ cat log 
4STD OUT
[13:31:52][user@machine: ~/src]$ 
[13:32:10][user@machine: ~/src]$ bash test > log 2>&1
[13:32:15][user@machine: ~/src]$ cat log 
4STD OUT
[13:32:18][user@machine: ~/src]$
```