# Redirect cron script output to file in home directory

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron

I have a Python script which outputs to standard out, and the scripts resides in `/usr/local/bin` so I run the following command to redirect the output: `./myscript >> /home/user/output.csv`.

However I need to run the script as a Cron job every minute (whether I am logged in or not) and I am unsure of the Cron syntax to redirect to "output.csv" which is in my home directory.

This is what I've come up with but I am fairly sure that redirecting from Cron won't be that simple:

```
 0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *  /usr/local/bin/myscript >> /home/user/output.csv
```

How do I do it correctly?

Comment: Have you tried this already? Have you tried putting your `./myscript >> /home/user/output.csv` in another file, say `job.sh`, and run that with a cronjob?

Comment: What you have there is far from every minute. Every minute is the simplest thing in cron: `* * * * *`. And redirecting from cron *is* that simple. (I'm talking about vixie cron syntax, by the way.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting the output of a cron job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982980/redirecting-the-output-of-a-cron-job)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is this easy. But also note the comment from 4ae1e1 on the cron syntax. For a job that runs every minute it has to be

`* * * * * /usr/local/bin/myscript >> /home/user/output.csv`

Comment: The cron job runs in your home directory; the full path is not strictly necessary or useful.