# Copy script output to file

Tags: bash, logging

I have a series of `bash scripts` that `echo` a lot of data to `stdout` and occasionally to `stderr`. There is a main `bash script` which then `imports` and/or `invokes` many other `bash scripts`.

I'm trying to implement something that will capture the output from not just the parent script, but all children scripts. I need to capture both `stdout` and `stderr` so that any issues from compilation, etc... get captured in this log file.

I'm aware of `tee` and of course the normal `stdout` redirect `>`... but these don't seem to work without either adding these commands to each line of every script, both parent and children. There's several thousand lines in these scripts, so adding a redirect to each line would be impractical, even using `sed`.

I've seen suggestions such as: [Redirect stderr and stdout in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script)

But these require editing every line in the scripts. Forcing my users to install `screen` is also impractical.

`UPDATE:`

Forgot to mention I want the output to still display on the console as well as write to the log. The scripts take several hours to run, and the user needs to know something is happening...

Comment: `script -c master_script.sh /path/to/some/log/file`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `yourmainscript 2>&1 | tee log` which will capture stdout and stderr from all imported/invoked scripts in `yourmainscript` while also showing it on screen.

Inside `yourmainscript`, you can get the same effect using:

```
echo "Redirecting the rest of script output to 'log'"
exec > >(tee log) 2>&1
rest of your code
```

To redirect just a certain section:

```
echo "Redirecting the next commands"
{
  cmd1
  cmd2
} > >(tee log) 2>&1
echo "Continuing as normal"
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I still want the output to also display on the console, as well as write to this log file. (the scripts take a few hours to run and the user needs to know something is happening still).

Comment: @SnakeDoc, assuming you want stderr and stdout to go to the same log, what's wrong with `main.sh 2>&1 | tee logfile` or `echo starting; { your_code_here; } 2>&1 | tee logfile` ??

Comment: @glennjackman if that will display the output to the console, as well as write it to the log, for all scripts (parent and children) for both `stdout` and `stderr`, then it may work. The `Makefile` will just need to invoke the `main.sh` as: `main.sh 2>&1 | tee runtime.log`. (in the middle of a large compilation atm, so I can't try it until it's completed).