# Difference between &> and > in Hive

Tags: hive

Can anyone tell me what is the difference betwwen `&>` and `>` in hive?

When to use which one?

For my work, `hive -f Script.hql > output.xls` works and `hive -f Script.hql &> output.xlsx` works?

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to hive but rather a feature in your shell. `command > file`  redirects stdout to a file and `command &> file` redirects both stderr and stdout to the same file.

See also [Redirect stderr and stdout in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script)