# What does "|&" mean in Bash?

Tags: bash

For example

```
echo "aaa" |& cat
```

What does `|&` mean here?

Is there a website recommended to look up those? Since most search engines can't support searching special characters.

Comment: FYI: `echo "aaa" |& cat` may lead to `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`&'` if `bash --version` is `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)`.

Answer (score 94):

From [`man 1 bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), section **Pipelines**:

> [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|⎪|&] command2 ... ]
>
> If |& is used, `command`'s standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to `command2`'s standard input through the pipe

So it is just like the pipe operator `|`, but piping both [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)).

Comment: @BallpointBen exactly. From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf: `If ‘|&’ is used, command1’s standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to command2’s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for 2>&1 |.`

Comment: @SantaXL It's worth noting that `|&` isn't widely supported and you are better off using `2>&1 |` for greater shell support across different platforms and different Linux distributions.

Answer (score 20):

This operator pipes both standard output and standard error from the left hand side to the right hand side.

The [Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) has a comprehensive index of all operators where you can look up these operators.

Answer (score 6):

If `|&` is used,

command_1’s standard error, in addition to it's standard output, is connected to command_2’s standard input through the pipe;

it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`.

**This implicit redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed after any redirections specified by the command.**

Answer (score 2):

`command1 |& command2` equal `command1 2>&1 | command2`