# go tool vet . |& grep -v vendor;true

Tags: bash, go, makefile

```
all: gotool
    @go build -v .
clean:
    rm -f apiserver
    find . -name "[._]*.s[a-w][a-z]" | xargs -i rm -f {}
gotool:
    gofmt -w .
    go tool vet . |& grep -v vendor;true

help:
    @echo "make - compile the source code"
    @echo "make clean - remove binary file and vim swp files"
    @echo "make gotool - run go tool 'fmt' and 'vet'"
    @echo "make ca - generate ca files"

.PHONY: clean gotool help
```

get confused with this commend `go tool vet . |& grep -v vendor;true`
and get error when make this...

```
$ make
gofmt -w .
go tool vet . |& grep -v vendor;true
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "&" unexpected
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'gotool' failed
make: *** [gotool] Error 2
```

Comment: Your shell doesn't support `|&`. Either don't use the `|&` syntax, or use a shell that supports it.

Comment: my bash is version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)， or any recommendation on how to rephase above syntax around `|&`？

Comment: You're probably not using bash, the error says `/bin/sh`, which is often a more basic shell. Are you just asking what `|&` means? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384999/what-does-mean-in-bash

Comment: so the whole sentence means ? `go tool vet . |& grep -v vendor;true`

Comment: Just a tip: you can tell vim to write swap files to a specific location. Add this to your .vimrc: `silent execute '!mkdir -p ~/.vim/mydir'`, then add the following lines `set directory=~/.vim/mydir`, `set backupdir=~/.vim/mydir`, and `set backupskip=~/.vim/mydir/*`

Answer (score 1):

The command attempts to redirect both standard output and standard error to `grep`. The portable (and subjectively better) way to do that is

```
go tool vet . 2>&1 | grep -v vendor || true
```

The trailing `true` will cause the `make` command to succeed even if `grep` fails to find any matches (i.e. there are no output lines which do not contain `vendor`).  Recall that `make` by default interrupts the compilation on the first error; this avoids an error for a command which is apparently only run for monitoring or possibly entertainment.