# How to log errors thrown from Google AddressSanitizer to a log file

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

AddressSanitizer by default throws all errors to shell itself, hence I tried running my ASAN build with following command;

```
>MCTester_ASAN>asan.log

==15619==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x61400000f9d0 at pc 0x46cff2 bp 0x7fffc062cb90 sp 0x7fffc062cb88
    #0 0x46cff1 in heapOutOfBoundWrite() /home/MemTest/main.cpp:49
    #1 0x46d68f in main /home/MemTest/main.cpp:116
    #2 0x7fbd3365bc35 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x1ec35)
    #3 0x40a0f8 (/x01/exd10/bin/MCTester_ASAN+0x40a0f8)

ASAN:SIGSEGV
==15619==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x00000044ff97 (pc 0x00000046cff2 sp 0x7fffc062cba0 bp 0x7fffc062cbb0 T0)
    #0 0x46cff1 in heapOutOfBoundWrite() /home/MemTest/main.cpp:49
    #1 0x46d68f in main /home/MemTest/main.cpp:116
    #2 0x7fbd3365bc35 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x1ec35)
    #3 0x40a0f8 (/x01/exd10/bin/MCTester_ASAN+0x40a0f8)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
Segmentation fault
```

But I still get the output to shell itself and not to the log file.

How to capture the output to a log file?

Answer (score 6):

To make sanitizer write report to a file you can pass `log_path=log_file` as part of `ASAN_OPTIONS`. It may be handy in case you want to see asan messages separated from any other output. Note: the filename will not be exactly `log_file` but rather a `log_file.$pid`.

Example:

```hs
$ cat test.cpp
int main() {
    *((char*)0) = 0;
}
$ g++ test.cpp -o a -fsanitize=address -g3
$ ASAN_OPTIONS="log_path=asan.log" ./a
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
$ cat asan.log.436962
=================================================================
==436962==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x5626d3a50196 bp 0x7ffd0b2c2b00 sp 0x7ffd0b2c2b00 T0)
==436962==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
==436962==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x5626d3a50196 in main /tmp/test.cpp:2
    #1 0x7f79c3a78151 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x28151)
    #2 0x5626d3a5008d in _start (/tmp/a+0x108d)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /tmp/test.cpp:2 in main
==436962==ABORTING
```

Answer (score 2):

> But I still get the output to shell itself and not to the log file.

This is because `AddressSanitizer` put errors in the [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29), but not in [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29).
There are a lot of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script) for your question.

For example:

```
yourcommand &>filename
```