# How to catch stderr of piped command in bash

Tags: bash, pipe, stderr

How do I catch error of that command into a var or following if-statement (nb `$?` always gets set `0`):

`mysqldump $db | gzip -9 > /opt/backup/dbdumps/$db-$stamp.sql.gz`

Default redirect `2> $foo` fails with *ambiguous redirect* error. I guess because bash does not know which command's stderr to redirect? But where to put some brackets or that stuff?

Comment: use `mysqldump $db 2>&1 | gzip -9...` or `mysqldump $db |& gzip -9`...

Comment: Also check for a variable called `PIPESTATUS`...

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script?rq=1)