# Startup shell script not producing output

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am working with Ubuntu 16.04 on an NVIDIA TX2 system and have a shell script `launcher.sh` containing the following commands:

`#!/bin/sh
cd /home/nvidia
sudo python test.py >> /home/nvidia/test_output.txt`,

basically implying to store the output of `test.py` in `test_output.txt`.

The `test.py`has one line: `print "Testing startup script!"`

I want this script (and more complicated scripts later on) to run automatically when the system boots up. To this end, I added it to the Startup Applications with the command `/home/nvidia/launcher.sh` and rebooted the system. The file `test_output.txt` is indeed created but there is no output written in it. I tested the script from the terminal and it works fine.

How do I make this to work from Startup Applications?

Comment: Have you added that path to `$PATH` var?

Comment: Do I add the PATH of the python file or the script or both?

Comment: Do you have to enter a password for sudo?

Comment: @Guy, yes, when I run the script from the terminal, it prompts me to enter the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Init scripts often don't have the complete environment initialized, e. g. `PATH`. In order to be executed you better provide the complete paths to commands.

On the other hand `sudo` is unnecessary here, as you obviously don't do anything that needs `root` permissions. If you need it, be aware that `sudo` is asking interactively for a password, which stalls the execution of the script, if the command you try to execute with it isn't explictely permitted in `/etc/sudoers`.

Provided `test.py` is located in `/home/nvidia`, and `python` in `/usr/bin`, the script should read

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/nvidia
/usr/bin/python test.py >> test_output.txt
```

And if you want to add error output to the outfile, which may be useful for debugging, make the last line

```
/usr/bin/python test.py >> test_output.txt 2&>1
```

or for a separate error log

```
/usr/bin/python test.py >> test_output.txt 2> test_error.log
```

Comment: I replaced `sudo python` with `/usr/bin/python` and it worked perfectly! May I ask why is `2&>1` needed for logging the output?

Comment: As I wrote it's for redirecting the **error output**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/637838/5794048