# Save linux console output in txt. file

Tags: linux, logging, server, console, capture

I'm just running an assetto corsa server on my linux server and Im wondering how it could be possible to "capture" the output of my console and save it in a txt file. (because AC hasn't a log system, but the console outputs nice information)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect stderr and stdout in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637827/608639)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to capture the ouput of your console while see it on your console at the same time:

```
someCommand | tee --append someFile.txt
```

if you want to print in the .txt file the error message it it occurs:

```
someCommand 2>&1 | tee --append someFile.txt
```

Comment: Can you see the console & have it written in the file at the same time?

Comment: As far as i can remember, no

Comment: Thanks anyway, Simo. Saved my day :D