# Python output redirecting

Tags: python, linux, io

When I'm running `python3` interpreter on Linux machine and trying to redirect it's `stdout` to file like this, nothing happens:

```
user@workmachine:~$ python3 > python.txt
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
\>>>
```

File `python.txt` remains empty while interpreter is running as well as after it was closed. All it's output is still in terminal.

On the other hand, if I'm redirecting `R` interpreter
the same way ( `R > R.txt` ) the result is as expected ( all output redirected to file, see nothing in terminal ).

What's the difference? Are python writes all it's output to another stream than `stdout`, or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/608639), [Redirect stderr and stdout in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637827/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww, the question you mention is about noninteractive mode. Please read the comment of my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case seems python send information to STDERR and not to STDOUT. So you should use redirect like:

```
user@workmachine:~$ python3 2> python.txt
```

Comment: It's common for interactive programs to write to stderr instead of stdout. For example, `read -p "Type something: "` will display its prompt on stderr.