# Are echo statements i.e. standard output from an other bash shell, logged anywhere?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging

I have some existing shell scripts, some of which have echo statements rather than logging statements.
In a 3 node cluster, if a non master node is down, the master node's script is triggered.
When I reboot the non master node, I need to view the echo statements in the master node's script to see what's happening.
The script is auto executed by a trigger which detects when a server is down.
How do I view the echo statements?

Comment: It depends how the script is run. Script output isn't automatically logged in general, but the "trigger" that's executing the script might save its output somewhere.

Comment: I don't think that's happening in this case. Will all echo statements be lost outside of the shell in which it's run?

Comment: Yes, they will.

Comment: `echo` itself does nothing but send bytes to standard output, whatever file that may be. The answer to this depends *entirely* on how standard output is set for the process in question.

Comment: What do you mean by setting a standard output @chepner

Comment: @dozer Whatever runs ("trigger"s) the script will, either explicitly or implicitly, provide the script with file handles for it to send standard and error output to. These could be a terminal (e.g. when you run things interactively), they could be disk file(s), pipe(s) to another program, /dev/null, whatever. One option is to set/replace those file handles so output goes somewhere like a file that you can then read. Or you could edit the script so it does proper logging.

Comment: `command` prints to the console where the command was started; `command >file 2>&1` Instead saves that output to a file you can inspect later. This is very basic Unix fundamentals.

Comment: Thanks guys. This helped. I managed to redirect the output to a file using your inputs and this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-bash