# How to append result of curl with a if check to a file?

Tags: bash

With the following:

```
curl URL | grep -i "KEYWORD" && "keyword found" || echo "keyword not found" >> result.txt
```

How can I get the results into the file? Seems this does not work with or without the file created.

Objective:

Search for keyword in curl result, if found append to file 'found' else append 'not found'.

Edit:

I figured it out:

```
curl URL | grep -i "keyword" && echo "found $(date)" >> result || echo "not found $(date)" >> result
```

Comment: `curl URL | tee result.txt | grep ....`

Comment: What is *"does not work"* mean? Also see [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/876239/608639), [Redirect stderr and stdout in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637827/608639) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: when i run my command, it will not create the file(if it wasnt created) and append to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output for a whole `if` command:

```
if curl URL | grep -i 'KEYWORD'; then echo "keyword found"; else echo "keyword not found"; fi >> result.txt
```

If it's not a single command, you can enclose the group in `{` `;}`:

```
{ command1; command2; command3; } >> result.txt
```

---

Note that `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3` can [produce unexpected results](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3). In particular, if `cmd1` succeeds but `cmd2` fails, `cmd3` will also run. `if` / `fi` is less error prone.

Comment: i want to append to file 'found' if keyword is found. i figured it out;; updated op with answer..