# How to redirect bash stderr to terminal, but also redirect stderr with stdout to log file?

Tags: linux, bash, sh, tee

I have a script that QA Manager runs.
I want him to take a look at terminal from time to time to take a note if any errors appear.

The problem is that the script have a ton of output that we do not need to see.

What I am trying to implement:

- stderr only goes to terminal
- stdout only goes to full-log.txt
- stderr goes to full-log.txt as well as stdout

Another way is to

- stderr with stdout go to full-log.txt
- stderr only go error-log.txt

Will be very grateful if someone can help with that.

Comment: `cmd 2>&1 | tee full-log.txt` could possibly be ok, if you want `stdout` on the terminal too.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect stderr and stdout in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with bash, using a process substitution, with the redirections performed in this order:

```sh
cmd 2> >(tee -a full-log.txt) >full-log.txt
```

Demo:

```sh
$ { echo "this is stdout"; echo "this is stderr" >&2; } 2> >(tee -a full-log.txt) >full-log.txt
this is stderr
$ cat full-log.txt
this is stdout
this is stderr
```