# How to capture mysqlsh output in bash script?

Tags: mysql, bash

I want to capture the output of a `mysqlsh` script (LOAD DATA):

```
logs=$(mysqlsh --user=$USER --password=$PASS --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock < /script.js)
echo $logs
```

script.js:

```
util.importTable('/my.csv', {schema: 'db', table: 'mytable', dialect: 'csv-unix', 
   fieldsTerminatedBy: ';', linesTerminatedBy: '\n', replaceDuplicates: true
   showProgress: false, bytesPerChunk: '200M', threads: 3, columns: [...]});
```

On the console I see:

```
WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Importing from file '/my.csv' to table `db`.`mytable` in MySQL Server at /var%2Frun%2Fmysqld%2Fmysqld.sock using 3 threads
[Worker000] db.mytable: Records: 351229  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
[Worker001] db.mytable: Records: 357374  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
[Worker002] db.mytable: Records: 352552  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
...
File '/my.csv' (21.11 GB) was imported in 5 min 22.7004 sec at 65.42 MB/s
Total rows affected in db.mytable: Records: 37129973  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

BUT: `echo $logs` shows an **empty line**.

Why is the `mysqlsh` output not captured here?

Comment: You're seeing STDERR, not STDOUT. Maybe `2>&1`.

Comment: Why am I seeing stderr? Can I somehow capture both err+out into the logs variable?

Comment: See: [Redirect stderr and stdout in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637827/3776858)

Comment: You're only redirecting STDOUT, that's why. The `2>&1` redirection maps them both to STDOUT.

Comment: Use syntax: `COMMAND >file.log 2>&1` and then `cat file.log` if you want to see it right away in your terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help above, indeed a `2>&1` at the end fixes the problem:

`.../script.js 2>&1)`