# gnuplot outputs strange text after plot command

Tags: macos, text, terminal, command-line, gnuplot

Sorry for the vagueness in the title, I don't know how else to describe it.
I am using gnuplot 5.4.5 on macOS Ventura 13.1. Whenever I try to plot something, wether a function or data from a file, the plot window containing the graph correctly appears, but the command line is littered with a bunch of text that I don't understand, like in the following example:

```
~ > gnuplot

G N U P L O T
Version 5.4 patchlevel 5    last modified 2022-09-28

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2022
Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type is now 'qt'
Options are '0 font "Arial,12"'
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
1   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada9c5c8 _ZN15MenuBarInstance22EnsureAutoShowObserverEv + 120
2   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada9c188 _ZN15MenuBarInstance14EnableAutoShowEv + 60
3   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada3f310 SetMenuBarObscured + 372
4   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada3eee8 _ZN13HIApplication15HandleActivatedEP14OpaqueEventRefhP15OpaqueWindowPtrh + 172
5   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada38fcc _ZN13HIApplication13EventObserverEjP14OpaqueEventRefPv + 296
6   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ad9ffcd0 _NotifyEventLoopObservers + 176
7   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada3896c AcquireEventFromQueue + 432
8   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada27c84 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 320
9   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada27b2c _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
10  AppKit                              0x00000001a75d4424 _DPSNextEvent + 632
11  AppKit                              0x00000001a75d35b4 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 728
12  AppKit                              0x00000001a75c79e4 -[NSApplication run] + 464
13  libqcocoa.dylib                     0x000000010403d7a4 qt_plugin_instance + 174652
14  QtCore                              0x0000000101727f74 _ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 520
15  QtCore                              0x000000010172c5cc _ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv + 132
16  gnuplot_qt                          0x00000001000ceb70 main + 832
17  dyld                                0x00000001a3f4be50 start + 2544
gnuplot> 1   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada2790c _ZN15MenuBarInstance22RemoveAutoShowObserverEv + 44
2   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada3f214 SetMenuBarObscured + 120
3   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada46390 _ZN13HIApplication11FrontUILostEv + 44
4   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada3f04c _ZN13HIApplication15HandleActivatedEP14OpaqueEventRefhP15OpaqueWindowPtrh + 528
5   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada38f70 _ZN13HIApplication13EventObserverEjP14OpaqueEventRefPv + 204
6   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ad9ffcd0 _NotifyEventLoopObservers + 176
7   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada3896c AcquireEventFromQueue + 432
8   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada27c84 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 320
9   HIToolbox                           0x00000001ada27b2c _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
10  AppKit                              0x00000001a75d4424 _DPSNextEvent + 632
11  AppKit                              0x00000001a75d35b4 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 728
12  AppKit                              0x00000001a75c79e4 -[NSApplication run] + 464
13  libqcocoa.dylib                     0x000000010403d7a4 qt_plugin_instance + 174652
14  QtCore                              0x0000000101727f74 _ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 520
15  QtCore                              0x000000010172c5cc _ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv + 132
16  gnuplot_qt                          0x00000001000ceb70 main + 832
17  dyld                                0x00000001a3f4be50 start + 2544
gnuplot>
```

Like I said, the graph displays fine and I get no errors, but this makes using gnuplot messy and cumbersome. I also never encountered this problem when using gnuplot form Ubuntu. Any ideas as to what could be causing it?

I tried changing the default qt terminal font (sans), that also caused an error message when plotting something, to Aerial in the .zshrc file - this solved the font issue but the text still appears.

**Edit: found partial fix**

After I encountered the exact same problem while using `matplotlib` 's `show` function, I looked it up and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74975596/matplotlibs-show-function-triggering-unwanted-output) question on Stack Overflow to which I refer for details. I confirm the workaround works for gnuplot as well.